# TFS API - Get merged changesets

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have a program that reads the lastest build and gets all the changesets from it. It is then possible to determine if the changset that I have it actually a merge, and where it was from.

Here's what I have:

```
List<IChangesetSummary> changeSets = InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(build);
IEnumerable<Changeset> changesetDetails = changeSets.Select(x => versionControlServer.GetChangeset(x.ChangesetId));

// Determine is the first changeset was a merge
changesetDetails.First().IsMerge // How to check is the changeset is part of a merge?
```

UPDATE:

Following the answers so far I have updated

```
foreach (var cs in changesetDetails)
{
    foreach (Change change in cs.Changes)
    {
        if ((change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Merge) == 0)
            continue;

        foreach(var m in change.MergeSources)
```

But `MergeSources` is always empty.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `VersionControlServer.GetChangesForChangeset` method instead. The last parameter indicates that merge source information should be included.

```
List<IChangesetSummary> changeSets = InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(build);
IEnumerable<Change> changes = changeSets.SelectMany(x => versionControlServer.GetChangesForChangeset(x.ChangesetId, false, Int32.MaxValue, null, null, true));

foreach (Change change in changes)
{
    if ((change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Merge) == 0) continue;                  
    foreach (var m in change.MergeSources)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: For me some of the merged CS are not included with this method, do you know what can be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether any of the `Changes` made inside a `Changeset` is of the [ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changetype.aspx) `Merge`.

I don't know if the following works, but you get the idea:

```
changesetDetails.First().Changes.Any(c => (c.ChangeType & ChangeType.Merge) > 0)
```

Comment: I did come across looking at the type of the change. However, when I then try and drill into MergeSource it's always empty.  I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to interrogate the files am see if the operation was "merge".

Comment: I've updated my question - I believe I have the right flag from the other answer, but the MergeSources aren't populated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of `VersionControlServer.GetChangeset` that accepts the `includeDownloadInfo` bool parameter. Setting this parameter to `true` will include the `MergeSources` in the returned changesets.

```
IEnumerable<Changeset> changesetDetails = changeSets.Select(x => versionControlServer.GetChangeset(x.ChangesetId, true, true));
```

[ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138628.aspx ]

Comment: This doesn't appear to make any difference.  The link that you included that the `includeDownloadInfo` is for getting information about the physical files; but regardless, MergeSources are still null

Comment: My mistake, see me later answer instead.