# TFS DB query to get merged changesets from one branch to another

Tags: tfs, report, warehouse

I would like to make a report that will show what changesets were promoted from one branch to another one. I've got all needed information about changesets in my query, but i cannot find a reference between changeset from the MAIN branch and changeset used to merge it to another branch.
Is there a way to get this by querying TfS_Warhouse?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommend to query information from TFS database directly.

You could use TFS API to achieve what you want. And also it's much easy to query the information. Here is a good example [TFS API - Get merged changesets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250748/tfs-api-get-merged-changesets) for you reference.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, but i'm not familiar with TFS API.  My goal is to create a report that will be available from web for anyone who have access to it. Is it possible to do this via API?